# How do I know the total number of downloaded files type = "file" multiple?

Tags: javascript

There is a problem that if you select files individually, only the last selected one will be sent, if you select several files and send them, then everything is fine - several files will be sent.

How do I know the total number of downloaded files type = "file" multiple?

```js
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
     

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;
            
            console.log(filesAmount);

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                
                let selectedFile = input.files[i];
        

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                   $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                    $($.parseHTML('<div>')).text(selectedFile.name).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add">
<div class="gallery"></div>
```

Upload files one at a time:
[image]

Download multiple files at once:
[image]

Comment: FYI, you can just do `$('<img>')` and it does `parseHTML` internally... Also, you've got the code that shows how to tell how many have been selected: `input.files.length`. It's not clear what you mean by "sent"; you don't have a `form` element in your HTML, and no JavaScript code to submit the form via ajax....

Comment: Could you explain what you want your code to do that it doesn't already do? You use `input.files.length` already, which I understand to be an answer to your question. But since that's already in your code, I think I must not understand what you need help with.